# How can I remove a zen-grid-item mixin declared in a previous media query?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, grid-layout

I've been using Zen Grids for responsive layouts for a while now, and somehow never came across this.  I've referenced the [documentation](http://zengrids.com/help/), but for the life of me cannot figure out how to do something which should be relatively simple.

I have a block which I set on the grid, such as:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">
  </div>

</div>

==========

.container {
  @include zen-grid-container();
}

.item {
  @include zen-grid-item(1, 1);
}
```

I then have a media query where, for whatever reason, I need to remove the item from the grid completely:

```
@media screen and (min-width:50em) {

  .item {
    ???
  }

}
```

To be clear, I'm not looking to re-declare the item to a different col-width/position, I just want to remove the mixin from being called completely.  I know I can just reset the CSS manually, but was wondering if there was a better way from any Zen Grid ninjas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just use

```
.item {
  display: none;
}
```

in your media query? That should hide it and probably remove the spacing it took up as well.